# what do the numbers in the Wordpress attribute_data field mean?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a CSV based export from a WooCommerce site. The attributes (both regular and global) all have an attribute_data field next to the data. For example, here is one:

| attribute:pa_weight | attribute_data:pa_weight | attribute_default:pa_weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.44 | 11|1|0 |  |

Some of these `attribute_data` values are: `1|1|0` , `5|1|0`, `3|1|0`, etc

It seems the last number is always zero and the middle is always 1. The first numbers varies.

Any ideas what these different numbers are for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have an export format like that, but by looking at the default Products > Export format, there are three consecutive columns: Attribute value(s), Attribute visible, Attribute global.

Therefore:

- First number: attribute value e.g. "red"
- Second number: attribute is "visible" i.e. from the product edit settings should be the "Visible on the product page" checkbox Yes/No
- Third number: attribute is "global" i.e. can be found under /wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=product&page=product_attributes as opposed to being added by hand in the product edit page

Comment: Thank you! That helps clear things up. I appreciate your help.